# Find sum of series $\sum_{r=1}^{117} =\frac{1}{2[\sqrt r]+1}$, where $[.]$ is greatest integer function

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

Simply substituting the values in the sum gives
$$\sum = \frac 13 + \frac 13 + \frac 13 +\frac 15 +\frac 15 + \frac 15 + \frac 15 +\frac 15...$$
$$\sum = 3(\frac 13) +5(\frac 15) +7(\frac 17) +9(\frac 19)...$$

Now the general idea would be to continue this series up to the last term which is $19(\frac{1}{19})$

But then adding those terms doesn’t give the right answer.

The problem arises because the second last term is actually $18(\frac{1}{21})$ instead of $18(\frac{1}{18})$

And so the so sum adds up to
$$\sum = \frac{69}{7}$$

What are indicators in such question to know that series isn’t going to go the way it is expected to?

Answer (score 2):

For these kind of sum we can use that

$$\sum_{r=1}^{N^2-1} \frac{1}{2[\sqrt r]+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{N-1} \frac{2k+1}{2k+1}=N-1$$

and in this case for $N=11$ we obtain

$$\sum_{r=1}^{120} \frac{1}{2[\sqrt r]+1}=10$$

therefore

$$\sum_{r=1}^{117} \frac{1}{2[\sqrt r]+1}=10-\frac3{21}=\frac{69}{7}$$

Comment: Please explain first line in detail

Comment: Hoye did you do the transformation from N^2-1 to N-1

Comment: @Alex Let make a scheeme for $r$ and $[\sqrt r]$ and you can see the pattern. For $r=1$ to $3$ we have $[\sqrt r]=1$, for $r=4$ to $8$ we have $[\sqrt r]=2$, and so on.